# Running Node with dumb-init inside a Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, tini

I am trying to use dumb-init in my docker container but the container OS cannot find the executable. My file is

```
FROM node:16 AS builder

RUN apt update
RUN apt install dumb-init

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn run build

FROM node:16 AS production

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/yarn.lock ./yarn.lock
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

and when I run it

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/bin/dumb-init": stat /usr/bin/dumb-init: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

Comment: You're not installing `dumb-init` in your final ("production") build stage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You final `nodejs:16` image is a debian based image, you however need to install `dumb-init` on it.

```
RUN apt-get install dumb-init
```

on debian / ubuntu based images

```
RUN apk add dumb-init
```

on Alpine based images

Comment: Actually, the solution was a combination of this and the comment left in the question iteslf.

Answer (score 5):

I think a better approach here is to just use the docker image for dumb-init.

For example..

```
FROM building5/dumb-init:1.2.1 as init

FROM node:16.15.0 as build
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM node:16.15.0 as prod
COPY --from=init /dumb-init /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "./server.js"]
```